# Cannot copy classes.jar file when I removed Android Studio project from one folder to another one?

Tags: android, android-studio, jar

When I removed a project from from one folder to another one, and used Android Studio to open it, ***3 errors pop up like below:***

> 1st

```
0:14:19 Cannot copy 'C:\Users\Workspace\AndroidStudio\Event\app\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.android.support.test\runner\0.5\jars\classes.jar'
to 'C:\Users\pc\.AndroidStudio2.2\system\jars\classes.jar'.
        Reason: null.
```

> 2nd

```
0:14:19 Cannot copy 'C:\Users\Workspace\AndroidStudio\Event\app\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.android.support.test\exposed-instrumentation-api-publish\0.5\jars\classes.jar'
to 'C:\Users\pc\.AndroidStudio2.2\system\jars\classes.jar'.
        Reason: null.
```

> 3rd

```
0:14:19 Cannot copy 'C:\Users\Workspace\AndroidStudio\Event\app\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.android.support.test\rules\0.5\jars\classes.jar'
to 'C:\Users\pc\.AndroidStudio2.2\system\jars\classes.jar'.
         Reason: null.
```

What could be causing this, and how can I prevent it?